# Using an "or" operator with an Int in Scala

Tags: scala

There's data I need to split into columns. The empty spaces must be distributed among the final columns. So if I have four elements and three columns, the columns will have these number of elements: 2, 1 and 1.

I need to know how many columns will be full. The answer is:

```
val full = data.length % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS
```

The problem with that is that the number of items is a multiple of the number of columns, this returns zero, which is not what I want. So I *could* do:

```
val full = if (data.length % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS == 0) NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS else 
  data.length % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS
```

This works, but does not feel very "Scala-like." It's definitely verbose and clumsy and the remainder operation either needs to be stored or performed twice. (Here, I picked the latter option.)

Is there a better way?

In Python, what I'd do is basically use the `or` operator with an `Int`, like this:

```
full = len(data) % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS or NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS
```

Done. But I can't think of something similar in Scala. Does it not exist or am I simply not seeing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using pattern matching like this

```
len % nCols match {
  case 0 => nCols
  case v => v
}
```

Note the second pattern matches any (non zero) value and delivers the mod value already calculated.

Comment: I prefer @Dima's solution because it looks more compact, but this is the best one so far, in all objectivity. Pattern-matching is at the basis of Scala. It's readable, it's clear, it's concise and it looks so obvious in retrospect that I feel like a complete idiot for not having seen it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Option(x).filter(_ != 0).getOrElse(numColumns)
```

Comment: Filtering an  `Option`! How did I not see that?